XSLT to reassign Sequence Number based on Key Field Value
I have a requirement to reassign the sequence number /MainHeader/Record/POSN with 8001,8002.... when we have two  segments which has same value in the field /VAR, If /Child -- > segment exists under /Record then same sequence number must be copied to the field /POSN inside /Child ..
my XSLT is by default generating sequence number for all records.
Sample input and output are attached.
Input:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<MainHeader>
    <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>1000</POSN>
        <VAR>1234</VAR>
        <field>41</field>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
      <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>2000</POSN>
        <VAR>45678</VAR>
        <field>41</field>
        <Child SEGMENT="1">
          <POSN>2000</POSN>
          <Union>UN</Union>
         </Child>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
      <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>2000</POSN>
        <VAR>45678</VAR>
        <field>42</field>
        <Child SEGMENT="1">
          <POSN>2000</POSN>
          <Union>UN</Union>
         </Child>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
        <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>3000</POSN>
        <VAR>778899</VAR>
        <field>43</field>
        <Child SEGMENT="1">
          <POSN>3000</POSN>
          <Union>UN</Union>
         </Child>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
          <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>4000</POSN>
        <VAR>778899</VAR>
        <field>44</field>
         <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
          <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>5000</POSN>
        <VAR>118899</VAR>
        <field>45</field>
         <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
      
      
</MainHeader>


** Desired Output:**
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<MainHeader>
    <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>1000</POSN>
        <VAR>1234</VAR>
        <field>41</field>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
      <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>8001</POSN>
        <VAR>45678</VAR>
        <field>41</field>
        <Child SEGMENT="1">
          <POSN>8001</POSN>
          <Union>UN</Union>
         </Child>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
      <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>8002</POSN>
        <VAR>45678</VAR>
        <field>42</field>
        <Child SEGMENT="1">
          <POSN>8002</POSN>
          <Union>UN</Union>
         </Child>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
        <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>8003</POSN>
        <VAR>778899</VAR>
        <field>43</field>
        <Child SEGMENT="1">
          <POSN>8003</POSN>
          <Union>UN</Union>
         </Child>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
          <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>8004</POSN>
        <VAR>778899</VAR>
        <field>44</field>
         <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
          <Record SEGMENT="1">
        <POSN>5000</POSN>
        <VAR>118899</VAR>
        <field>45</field>
         <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>value1</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
        <Subsegment SEGMENT="1">
          <Qua>Value2</Qua>
        </Subsegment>
      </Record>
      
      
</MainHeader>

** XSLT I used is below:**
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="segments-by-field" match="Record" use="POSN"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MainHeader>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="MainHeader/Record" group-by="POSN">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </MainHeader>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record">
   
    <Record>
        <POSN><xsl:value-of select="8000 + position()"/></POSN>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </Record>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Please review it once.

Your code groups the Record elements on POSN, the text seems to suggest that you want to group by VAR (or at least that might be one interpretation of "reassign the sequence number /MainHeader/Record/POSN with 8001,8002.... when we have two segments which has same value in the field /VAR"). Please clarify. As for passing the sequence number one to children or descendants, consider to use a (tunnel) parameter with apply-templates. And obviously push all nodes through templates if you want to change content, if you throw in copy-of you can't change anything.

This is not a trivial task and I doubt there is a simple solution. Grouping the records does not help if you want the numbering to be sequential across the groups.
Try perhaps something like:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="rec-by-var" match="Record" use="VAR" />
<xsl:variable name="rec-ids" select="//Record[count(key('rec-by-var', VAR)) > 1]/generate-id()" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record[generate-id()=$rec-ids]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="multi">
            <xsl:with-param name="new-posn" select="8000 + index-of($rec-ids, generate-id())" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="POSN" mode="multi">
    <xsl:param name="new-posn" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$new-posn"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


I think the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet does the job:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/MainHeader">
    <xsl:variable name="duplicates" as="xs:string*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//VAR" group-by=".">
        <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) gt 1">
          <xsl:sequence select="string(.)"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <MainHeader>
      <xsl:iterate select="Record">
        <xsl:param name="seq" select="8001"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="VAR = $duplicates">
            <Record>
              <xsl:copy-of select="@*, POSN"/>
              <VAR>{$seq}</VAR>
              <xsl:copy-of select="* except (POSN, VAR)"/>
            </Record>
            <xsl:next-iteration>
              <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq+1"/>
            </xsl:next-iteration>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
      </xsl:iterate>
    </MainHeader>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

